# TypeScript: Getting names (as string) of Union's possible types?

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

Is it possible to get names of Union's possible types?

Given that I have defined these interfaces and type aliases:

```
// https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions

interface Square {
    kind: "square";
    size: number;
}

interface Rectangle {
    kind: "rectangle";
    width: number;
    height: number;
}

type Shape = Square | Rectangle;
```

Can I get a union of string like this?

```
type ShapeName = 'Square' | 'Rectangle';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do smth like that:

```js
interface Square {
  kind: "square";
  size: number;
}

interface Rectangle {
  kind: "rectangle";
  width: number;
  height: number;
}

type Shape = Square | Rectangle;

type ShapeName = Shape['kind'] // 'square' | 'rectangle';
```

Please keep in mind, you are unable to obtain interface name unless you map some how it.

Comment: > _you are unable to obtain interface name_ – I see. Then I have to use a property like `kind` in the example, right? Thank you!

Comment: Right, you should use `kind` in this case