# Typescript: Is it possible to use names of union type members as strings?

Tags: typescript, union, tostring

Is there a way in Typescript to **convert union member to string**?

Like following:

```
type T = TObjectA | TObjectB

// use somewhere as string literal union:

type TAsString = "TObjectA" | "TObjectB"
```

Simplified example of actual intent:

```
import type { user, address, invoice } from "@/db-codegen"

type TModel =  user | address | invoice

type MyProps = {
    model: TModel
    // This obviously wont't work. So as .toString() and other naive attempts
    modelName: `${TModel}`
    // desired outcome: "user" | "address" | "invoice"
}
```

This is probably a duplicate of [TypeScript: Getting names (as string) of Union's possible types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65886571/typescript-getting-names-as-string-of-unions-possible-types), but it has only one – and not really satisfactory – answer.

I was hoping this thread [String Union to string Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44480644/string-union-to-string-array) could help, but it probably addresses a slightly different problem.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Chances are, what you need is a discriminated union: otherwise your `MyProps` type can technically have `user` in `model`, yet have `modelName` of "address". There is no 1-to-1 relation between `model` and `modelName` in your type.

Comment: @Terry You're right ,I didn't think of that. Thank you.

Comment: The question that you've linked is probably the way you want to do going forward: a discriminated union.

Comment: The issue I see is that I can't leverage the autogenerated types from db. The only option I see is to add a 'name' column to all the tables, to have it accessible in TS, which is… meh :/.